# "reverse" authorized pages being redirected to login

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, redirect

So, I have a page that I want only anonymous users to see, and authenticated users to be redirected. So, like this:

```
<location path="Login_ForgotUserID.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The problem is, when an authenticated user attempts to access it, it redirects them to the login page.  How can I send them someplace more logical?  obtw, I'm confined to .NET v2.0x

Comment: Well, the whole point of doing this through the web.config is to take advantage of the SiteMap controls.  So, for example, if an anonymous user is on this page and clicks Login (LoginStatus control), it attempts to return them to the page.  However, when the system gets the request, the user is not authorized to see the resource and the resulting action is to send them to the login page.  What I need is a way to test the resource I'm redirecting to to see if the user can access it, and if not handle it differently.

Comment: Ok, here's how I understand it to work:
- a SiteMap has a list of links that users can go to.  That list gets trimmed by the permissions set forth in web.config.
- the usual flow is from anonymous to authenticated.  In the the web.config, this is achieved by "deny ?" then "allow *" to block unauthenticated users.
- when a user attempts to go to a page that they don't have access to, the site redirects them to the login page.
So, the problem is, ASP assumes that "if you don't have permission, you have to go to the login page".  Which is not always true in all cases.  I need a way around that.

Comment: Security Trimming will hide the link in your menu for you even under this scenario, so this is just about direct access to the URL, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add `if ( Request.IsAuthenticated ) { Response.Redirect ...` to the Page_Load event of the page you don't have to worry about configuring it out?  Unfortunately you can only config a single page to handle Login and if someone doesn't have access they will be directed to it.  You could also just check the ReturnURL on Login to see if it came from a page and the user is Authenticated, but that to me is a hokey solution.

Comment: This is entirely correct. There's no way to do this in the web.config and you'll need to write code to handle it. You **can** control it partially through either a customer config section or the app keys section of the config file though.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answer is that I need to modify the menu before it renders.  I never found a way to handle the SiteMap by changing the authoriztion/SecurityTrimming.  So I decided to try to modify the SiteMap at the source, and I found out how to modify the MenuItems [as they were bound](http://forums.asp.net/p/1065135/3588876.aspx).  This seemed the most effective course.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this in the web.config.  In the Login_ForgotUserID.aspx page probably check if the user was authenticated before loading/rendering.  If the user is authenticated then redirect them to some harmless home or default page.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using roles here as well.

If you were to add all users by default to a role, say "authenticated" then you could have:

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny roles="authenticated" />
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

You must ensure that deny is fisrt in the list, as these are processed in order, and the first match is used.

Two other methods to do a similar thing:

1. Write a [custom sitemap provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178432.aspx) to ensure that these pages aren't returned to the tree view control when the user is authenticated.
2. Write a [control adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter.aspx) for your treeview control to ensure that these pages aren't rendered by it.